# Redux Reducer updated value but not reflected in props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I set some values in React Redux store while the ComponentDidMount() function. Redux Dev Tools displays that the state has been updated. But in `props` It doesn't get changed.

My reducer.js is,

```
const inititalState = {
    slickColumns: null,
    slickData: null
}

const reducer = (state = inititalState, actions) => {
    switch(actions.type) {
        case actionsTypes.SET_SLICK_GRID_COLUMNS: {
            return {
              ...state,
              slickColumns: columns
            };
        }
        case actionsTypes.SET_SLICK_GRID_DATA: {

            return {
              ...state,
              slickData: [...mock_slick_data]
            };
        }
        default: {
            return state;
        }
    }
}

export default reducer;
```

action.js,

```
import * as actions from './actions';
export const setSlickGridColumns = () => {
    return {
        type:actions.SET_SLICK_GRID_COLUMNS
    }
}
export const setSlickGridData = () => {
    return {
        type: actions.SET_SLICK_GRID_DATA
    }
}
```

main.js, (Mapping Redux to state)

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    slickColumns: state.slickColumns,
    slickData: state.slickData
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onSetSlickDataColumns: () => {
      dispatch(actionTypes.setSlickGridColumns());
    },
    onSetSlickData: () => {
      dispatch(actionTypes.setSlickGridData());
    }
  };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Dimensions()(Home));
```

in ComponentDidMount function,

```
this.props.onSetSlickDataColumns(); // able to see this method is running and the state is updated in Redux Dev Tools
this.props.onSetSlickData();
console.log(this.props.slickColumns); // getting null here. 
dv.setItems(this.props.slickData);
```

Even thought the state is updated in store, I am still not able to get the data in the props? why? any ideas?

index.js,

```
import slickReducer from './store/reducers/SlickGrid';
const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(
  slickReducer,
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk))
);
const app = (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>

);
ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById("root"));
```

[Edit]: Initially I set initialState object properties as 'null;
Adding my Redux Screenshot here,
[image]

Adding extra some logs in here. This might helpful to resolve this issue. Actually the grid instance is created in `ComponentDidMount()` method.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("[componentDidmount]....");
    this.props.onSetSlickDataColumns();
    this.props.onSetSlickData();
    console.log(this.props);

    if (this.props.slickColumns.length !== 0) {
      const grid = (this.gridInstance = new Grid(
        this.grid,
        dv,
        this.props.slickColumns,
        options
      ));

     //  ------------------
     }
 }
```

When doing grid object, It should not have empty columns, and empty DataView.

I called the `setSlickGridColumns` and `setSlickGridData` method in various lifecycle methods such as `constructor`, `componentWillMount` and put console logs for props in `mapStateToProps`, `constructor`, `componentWillMount`, `render` and `componentDidMount` methods also. From the logs what I am getting is,

```
[mapStateToProps]
this.props.slickColumns: null

[componentConstructor].... calling onSetSlickDataColumns() and onSetSlickData() methods here..
this.props.slickColumns: null

[componentwillmount].... calling onSetSlickDataColumns() and onSetSlickData() methods here..
this.props.slickColumns: null

[render] 
this.props.slickColumns: null

[componentDidmount].... calling onSetSlickDataColumns() and onSetSlickData() methods here..
this.props.slickColumns: null

[mapStateToProps]
this.props.slickColumns: Array(300) // Here props values are set

[render]
this.props.slickColumns: Array(300)
```

From the logs, what I understand is, The data has to be filled before the `componentDidMount`() method. But It doesn't setting up even though I dispatched reducer function in `constructor` and `ComponentWillMount`. Hope this logs help to resolve this problem.

Comment: What do you mean by _Not reflected in the props?_ Can you share more details about the issue?

Comment: It's an async call you won't be able to get here.

Comment: Can you display the props in render to really understand if it is updated or not?

Comment: where do `columns` in your reducer come from?

Comment: Just a global variable in the reducer.js file. Actually my initialState properties are 'null' Modified the question a bit.

Answer (score 3):

Problem is you are not setting new data in your reducer you can see

```
const reducer = (state = inititalState, actions) => {
    switch(actions.type) {
        case actionsTypes.SET_SLICK_GRID_COLUMNS: {
            return {
              ...state,
              slickColumns : columns   // you have to pass your new data as payload from your function : actions.payload
            };
        }
        case actionsTypes.SET_SLICK_GRID_DATA: {

            return {
              ...state,
              slickData: [...mock_slick_data] // same here 
            };
        }
        default: {
            return state;
        }
    }
}
```

You can pass your data when you dispatch an action

```
dispatch(actionTypes.setSlickGridColumns('Pass your data here '));
```

Then you can get your data as argument like

```
export const setSlickGridColumns = (data) => {
    return {
        type:actions.SET_SLICK_GRID_COLUMNS,
        payload : data // pass your data as payload 
    }
}
```

Now you can use your data in **reducer** like actions.payload

```
 .......

 case actionsTypes.SET_SLICK_GRID_COLUMNS: {
                return {
                  ...state,
                  slickColumns : action.payload 
                };
 ........
```

Comment: let me know if you have any query

Comment: @PrakashKarena: Sorry. I understand your answer. I did one thing wrong in the question. my initialState properties are null. So If I set to columns means, it will be get changed right? But its not working.

Comment: please update your code with updated one and let me know

Comment: you are trying to access `columns` in your reducer. from where this columns came ???

Comment: its just a global variable in reducer.js having the columns content object.

Comment: I modified the question. My initialState properties are null.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206918/discussion-between-prakash-karena-and-smith-dwayne).

Answer (score 1):

try below code -> you need to return the dispatch inside the mapDispatchToProps like below

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onSetSlickDataColumns: () => {
      return dispatch(actionTypes.setSlickGridColumns());
    },
    onSetSlickData: () => {
      return dispatch(actionTypes.setSlickGridData());
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: If it is oneline statement in arrow function, then it will be behave as return the statement right? anyway I put return statement there. But not working.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you're not going to get updated props in `componentDidMount` lifecycle hook, as you are dispatching your function after your component is mounted. You'll get updated props in your `render`, `componentWillReceiveProps` (deprecated), `getDerivedStateFromProps` and some other lifecycle hooks. You can read more about which lifecycle hooks are being called when props are updated in the [official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html) of react.
And then you're missing return statement in mapDispatchToProps as mentioned in one other answer.

Comment: Can you log and see what is in redux state in `mapStateToProps` or attach the logs here as well. And is mapStateToProps running after dispatching the actions?